Clear case new snapshot view not visible in explorer
I'm quite new in ClearCase.
I wrote a script that creates a new snapshot view in Windows, after success creation - I see it in folder (via windows explorer), I can't see it in 'Clear case explorer'. I need manually to right click in CC explorer to add view shortcut.
Any idea how to automate it ?
I looked in the man of cleartool but I couldn't see anything that should mean add shortcut.

I also had the same issue, ClearCase shortcut didn't appear automatically.
what I found out till now is that adding the shortcut to the explorer isn't available in cleartool, due to cleartool is a unix tool wrapped with a window exe, and explorer is only a window tool.
The best way I found to overcome this issue is, after creating the view, popup a clear description for the user how to add shortcut manually.
